# Subsetting Data based on selected months in R

Tags: r

```
Year         tot_precip
1/1/1989     0
1/2/1989    .23
1/3/1989    0
1/4/1989    .43
1/5/1989    0.254
1/6/1989    0
1/7/1989    0
1/8/1989    0
1/9/1989    0
1/10/1989   .21
```

I am trying to subset my precipitation data based on certain months.I did some research.

```
tt=as.POSIXct(paste(prec$Year,prec$tot_precip), format="%m/%d/%Y")
datZoo <- zoo(prec[,-c(1,2)], tt)
month <- function (x) as.numeric(format(x, "%m"))
veranoIdx <- which(month(tt) %in% 6:8)
veranoZoo <- datZoo[veranoIdx]
veranoZoo
```

The above code worked to extract Year column based on certain months (June,July august) but I am lost about how to extract precipitation values for those dates(i.e veranoZoo series)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering input as:

```
dft <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "Year         tot_precip

                  1/1/1989     0

                  1/2/1989    .23

                  1/3/1989    0

                  1/4/1989    .43

                  1/5/1989    0.254

                  1/6/1989    0

                  1/7/1989    0

                  1/8/1989    0

                  1/9/1989    0

                  1/10/1989   .21",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

you can just use `tidyverse` functions and try:

```
dft %>% filter(month(Year) %in% c(6,7,8))
```

which gives:

```
      Year tot_precip
1 1/6/1989          0
2 1/7/1989          0
3 1/8/1989          0
```

Comment: i tried following code.                                                                   wood=read.csv(file = "woodruff.csv",header=TRUE)
wood[is.na(wood)]<- 0
x=data.frame(wood,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
x %>% filter(month(Year) %in% c(6,7,8))                                                               the error i am getting now is                                                                                   Error in filter_impl(.data, dots) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: most likely your `Year` isn't formatted properly. You can check out datetime types n R and their [conversion functions](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `Lines` as in the Note below, read the data into a zoo object.  Since this is evidently monthly data it would be best to use `"yearmon"` class as the index.  Now use `subset` to get the subset for June, July, August.

```
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, header = TRUE, FUN = as.yearmon, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
subset(z, cycle(z) %in% 6:8)
```

giving this zoo series:

```
Jun 1989 Jul 1989 Aug 1989 
       0        0        0
```

This would also work:

```
z[cycle(z) %in% 6:8]
```

(If your data is in a file `myfile.dat` then replace `text=Lines` with just `"myfile.dat"` in the `read.zoo` statement.)

**Note:**

```
Lines <- "Year tot_precip
1/1/1989 0
1/2/1989 .23
1/3/1989 0
1/4/1989 .43
1/5/1989 0.254
1/6/1989 0
1/7/1989 0
1/8/1989 0
1/9/1989 0
1/10/1989 .21"
```

Comment: @ G. Grothendieck Thanks.  I tried the above code. But some how i am getting error with FUN=as.yearman. I changed the code without FUN=as.yearman as follows                                                                                                                                  wood=read.csv(file = "woodruff.csv",header=TRUE)
wood[is.na(wood)]<- 0
x=data.frame(wood)
k <- read.zoo(x, header = TRUE, sep = ",", format = "%m/%d/%Y")
subset(k, cycle(k) %in% 6:8)............The result I am getting is Data:
numeric(0)

Comment: You must use yearmon to use cycle.

Comment: k <- read.zoo(x, header = TRUE, sep = ",",FUN = as.yearmon, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
Warning message:
In zoo(rval3, ix) :
  some methods for “zoo” objects do not work if the index entries in ‘order.by’ are not unique

Comment: As the warning says zoo objects can't have duplicate times.  The data in the question has none.